# Backing Up Symlinks

Tags: windows, hard-drive, file-transfer, symbolic-link, external-drive

I may have dug myself a deep hole ...

I am running Windows 8.1. I can ask for temporary administrator privileges, but some requests get denied for policy reasons. Media in question is on a single volume NTFS external drive. I have space issues and need to move to a bigger single volume NTFS external drive.

I have been using Link Shell Extension to create symlinks on the original external drive to both files and folders on the same drive. Within Link Shell Extension, I've always chosen "hardlinks" for files and "hardlink clones" for folders. After some experimentation I'd found that these work best with the software I'm using to run the files or access the folders.

I want to copy the original files and their hardlinks, and the original folders and their hardlink clones, to the new drive. And, of course, I want those symlinks to refer to the new drive rather than the old one.

I have had zero success with this. I am ready to start over and am open to any and all suggestions.

I have consulted many pages on this site and others. I thought Far Manager would solve my problem, but I have been unable to get it to copy the symlinks. Instead, it creates multiple copies of the files and folders.

I have confirmed this with Sysinternals Disk Usage. It shows 6K files in 54Gb, but 19K files in 178Gb with the -u switch (to count up symlinks and files) on the old drive. On the new drive, it always shows 19K files and 178Gb with or without the -u switch.

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was that our IT people run a tight ship. I have had them refuse to temporarily grant administrator privileges because what I want to do violates their policies.

Answer (score 2):

Use a disk imaging solution to copy the entire volume to a new drive. Since NTFS symbolic links are stored in the volume's MFT, they'll happily "transfer" to the new drive along with everything else.

You can copy an entire drive, or only a partition, depending on your needs.

My personal recommendation for cloning software is [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org). According to their website:

> Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program similar to True Image® or Norton Ghost®. It helps you to do system deployment, bare metal backup and recovery.

CloneZilla can be [downloaded here](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) and [documentation is here](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-usage/clonezilla-live-usage.php).

Comment: I made a good faith effort on this one, and can't get it to work. I do not have a FAT hard drive on which Clonezilla can be installed. I do not have a CD-ROM drive at all. I do have a FAT flashdrive, and did make a bootable flashdrive with Tuxboot — but I do not have enough BIOS control to authorize booting from it.

Suggestions?

Is this a job for cloning software? Or was my initial path of doing it with Far Manager (or something like that) workable?

I am also not sure if I need something as sophisticated as Clonezilla. The drive has little or no software. It's mostly videos.

Comment: I took the external drive home, and was able to get Clonezilla to do what I needed.

But, I'd still appreciate a solution that's more workable at the office, where I don't have the same privileges.

Comment: And I am not sure if this should go in a different thread or not. Clonezilla has solved my space problem, and given me a new backup. But, what if I want to back up to a remove drive on our network, or to the cloud on something like Backup and Sync. Clonezilla won't work for those, will it?

Comment: @boobounder Since this question already has an answer, you are correct to presume you need to ask a separate question.